# /usr/bin/sort to sort a file according to the third field

Tags: macos, sorting, terminal

I have got a file looks like:

> ??:??:??   UNKNOWN-VENDOR      100
>
> 00:11:d9   TiVo    951
>
> cc:3a:61   SAMSUNG ELECTRO MECHANICS CO., LTD.     259
>
> 84:1b:5e   NETGEAR     82
>
> 74:e2:f5   Apple   829

Fields are separated by a tab character. 
What combination should I use to sort this file from the highest number of bytes to lowest.
Number of bytes is the last field of a file.
I have tried to use:

> /usr/bin/sort -nk3 filename.txt

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page:

```
   -t, --field-separator=SEP
          use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition
```

So you want

```
sort -t $'\t' -nk3 filename.txt
```

Comment: How do you call from C? If using `exec`, the `$'\t'` is not processed by a shell, but passed literally to `sort`. If using `system`, it's probably using `sh`, which may not be processing `$'\t'` since it is a `bash` extension.

Comment: I am using `execl`. So how do I have to type it inside my program?

Comment: Drop the `$`. The C compiler will convert the `\t` to a literal tab for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to take the last field and print it in the beginning and then use that to do `sort`. `-r` option uses the reverse order meaning highest to lowest.

```
awk '{print $NF, $0}' filename.txt | sort -nk1r | awk '{$1="";print $0}'
```